# Restore SQL Server database from a script

Tags: sql-server, azure, restore

I have a database stored on SQL Server with my web site at a regular windows hosting solution. I need to migrate to Azure.
The only backup mean I have is to use SQL Server Management Studio and do a Task -> Generate scripts that saves schema and data in a sql file. I did it and I got a 260Mb file.
My question is about importing that to Azure. Can I do it in Mngt Studio too? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have exported it all to scripts, yes, you can run them against your SQL Database. However, before you do that I'd suggest looking at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/. It might shed some light on other options that will include verifying compatibility.  The BacPac method might be better than the scripts.

To answer the specific question of using SSMS with Azure SQL DB, this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-azure-ssms/ shows how to make the connection.

Comment: Thanks. The first document is a very good reference and it directed me to the migration wizard on codeplex. It appears that my db is not compatible so I have to use the wizard. I have in the middle of the task but I will surely set your answer as the solution.